# Error "invalid object name" after select into temporary table

Tags: c#, sql-server, temp-tables

I'm porting a working code to Microsoft Sql Server 2016 from a different dbms.
The sql looks like

```
SELECT many_fields INTO #this_repository FROM complex_join WHERE parametric_cond
```

I open the connection

```
OdbcCommand server_cmd = new OdbcCommand(SQL_extractor_server, DbConnection);
OdbcParameter refresh_from_par = new OdbcParameter("@refresh_from",refresh_from);
OdbcParameter refresh_to_par = new OdbcParameter("@refresh_to",refresh_to);
server_cmd.Parameters.Add(refresh_from_par);
server_cmd.Parameters.Add(refresh_to_par);
server_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
server_cmd.Dispose();
```

and then execute some commands always inside that connection.

```
OdbcCommand tot_rows_cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'tot_rows' FROM #this_repository",DbConnection);
tot_rows = (int)tot_rows_cmd.ExecuteScalar();
tot_rows_cmd.Dispose();
```

Can you explain the error or suggest where to look at?
Thank you!

### Further attempts

1. I've moved the code and the connection string from
   `System.Data.Odbc` to `System.Data.SqlClient`
2. I've added `Pooling=false;` to the connection string
3. I've inserted other code (just a `SELECT @@spid` from an
   `ExecuteScalar`) to double check that the `spid` is always the same
4. I've debugged the return code (`int`) of the first `ExecuteNonQuery`
   and it is 0
5. I've executed the SQL from SqlDbx - *one after the other* - and it does work as expected
6. Tried from C# code with only one `SqlCommand` and two statements separated by `;`: that also *does* work but it is *not* what I'm trying to accomplish

Unfortunately no luck till now!

Comment: Temp table like this only exist inside the session they are created in.  If you close the connection and create a new one you lose the temp table.

Comment: I dont close the connection. The code is working on the other dbms where I assume the rule is more or less the same. What am I missing?

Comment: You mentioned the same connection but that doesn't appear to be the case based on the symptoms. Consider running a trace to verify.

Comment: Based on the code why should the connection change? Maybe some settings in the new connection string that I have to add? I'm a developer not a db admin so I'm not sure if the trace is a practical available option for me, but if you elaborate more... thanks

Comment: Is there any code between the `server_cmd.Dispose();` and `OdbcCommand tot_rows_cmd = new OdbcCommand...`?

Comment: @DanGuzman no because the first command creates the temp table without doing anything else and the second one just select from the above temp table

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in ADO.NET

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23238075/6996876) clearly explains which is the root cause (and incidentally why it works in a Sql client):

I've tried by hard coding the parameters in the SQL and the issue doesn't show up.